# How do I call a JS function from a different file in the Rails asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, encapsulation, asset-pipeline

This is probably more a general JS encapsulation issue than Rails asset pipeline.

In the asset pipeline I have some general JS files that are used everywhere:

*app/assets/javascripts/pickers.js.cofeee*

```
jQuery ->

  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    timeFormat: 'h:mmtt',
    ampm: true,
    hourGrid: 4,
    minuteGrid: 10

  $('.datepicker').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

I also target body classes to run specific JS on controller/action specific pages:

*app/assets/javascripts/employees.js.cofeee*

```
jQuery ->

  if $('.employees.edit').length

    # initialize datepickers when adding new nested fields
    $('form').live 'nested:fieldAdded', (e) ->
      $(e.field).find('.datepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

Now this isn't the most cumbersome example of repetition but hypothetically if I wanted to move this datepicker code into a function and then call it in the employees.js.coffee file, how could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You extract the function into the global scope (outside of `jQuery`). Then it's available anywhere in your Javascript code as it becomes a member of the `window` object.

You should read about [scopes in Javascript](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes).

Comment: I usually avoid putting everything in `window`. Namespacing keeps code organized.